# Smarty loop section, adding <li> </li> every 4 but sometimes less

Tags: php, smarty

I have loop that generates:

```
< li > 1 2 3 < / li > 4 5 6 < li > 7 8 9 < / li > 10 11 12 < li > 13 14 15 < / li >
```

But my problem is that sometimes loop will have less results at end. And on end, there always need's to be < / li >. So it can look like that,

```
< li > 1 2 3 < / li > 4 5 6 < li > 7 8 < / li >
```

or

```
< li > 1 2 3 < / li > 4 5 6 < li > 7 < / li >
```

I have come up with such code, but it does not work as it should,

```
{section name=attribs loop=14}

{assign var=zamkniecie value=''}

{if $smarty.section.attribs.iteration % 5 == 0 or $smarty.section.attribs.iteration == 1}
        < li > {$smarty.section.attribs.iteration}
{/if}

{if $smarty.section.attribs.iteration % 4 == 0}
        < / li > {$smarty.section.attribs.iteration}
        {assign var=zamkniecie value=$smarty.section.attribs.iteration}
{/if}

{/section}

{if !$zamkniecie} < / li > {/if}
```

Thanks,

Comment: Easy to solve in PHP. Why use smarty...

Comment: @OIS Even easier to solve in Smarty. :P

Comment: I got structure in smarty. I know it is easy, but with that math conditions always had problems :(

Comment: In PHP: $items = range(1,14); $result = implode('</li><li>', array_map(function($item) { return implode(' ', $item); }, array_chunk($items,3)));echo "<ul><li>", $result, "</li></ul>";

Comment: @OIS Fine, whatever. Vim is better than Emacs, tabs are better than spaces, Macs are better than Windows PCs, and templating engines are a waste of space. Does this question represent a good reason to abandon Smarty? No.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `.first` instead of `.iteration == 1`, and `.last` to spot the last run through the loop. For maths like this, it is also more useful to use `.index`, which starts at `0`, rather than `.iteration`, which starts at `1`. You also want to check `% 3` in both if statements - in your example, one is making groups of 5 and the other of 4!

I think this should work:

```
{section name=attribs loop=14}

{* Open an item if this is the first entry (#0), or any that is divisible by 3 (#3, #6, etc) *}
{* Note that the .first is actually redundant, because 0 % 3 == 0 anyway *}
{if $smarty.section.attribs.index % 3 == 0 or $smarty.section.attribs.first}
        <li>
{/if}

{* Output the current item *}
{$smarty.section.attribs.iteration}

{* Close the current item if this is the last entry, or is the end of a group of 3 *}
{* The test is for indexes which leave a remainder of 2 when divided by 3: #2, #5, etc *}
{if $smarty.section.attribs.index % 3 == 2 or $smarty.section.attribs.last}
        </li>
{/if}

{/section}
```

Comment: It does not work, loop 40 and it gives me this: < li > 1 2 3 < li > 4 5 6 < li > 7 8 9 < li > 10 11 12 < li > 13 14 15 < li > 16 17 18 < li > 19 20 21 < li > 22 23 24 < li > 25 26 27 < li > 28 29 30 < li > 31 32 33 < li > 34 35 36 < li > 37 38 39 < li > 40 Like it would only include first "if" and on end it does not place < / li >

Comment: @Cameleon I think you may have introduced a typo somewhere, or perhaps copied a version where I had made one - I edited it a couple of times. It works fine for me.

Comment: Yes, my bad. Really thank you it is working wonderfully, big beer to you.